# Include multiple yum repositories in a single config file on red hat 6.0

Tags: redhat

How can I set multiple yum repositories in single repos file enabled at the same time.

For example this is what I have . Is this possible? If yes how will it process files?
If this is not possible how can I have multiple repositories at the same time? Do I need separate .repo files?

```
name=core-0
baseurl=http://your.url:80/cobbler/ks_mirror/installs
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1

[updates]
name=Redhat-x86_64-UPDATES
baseurl=http://your.url:80/cobbler/repo_mirror/updates
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
```

Comment: As I know, we can use multiple yum repositories. The setting examples can be found in the Redhat home page. See [Example 8.6. A sample /etc/yum.repos.d/redhat.repo file](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/sec-setting_repository_options)

Answer (score 1):

Technically, yum repositories are loaded from */etc/yum.conf* and it just includes the repositories directory of */etc/yum.repos.d* in most cases. You can put as many repositories as you want in a single file, as long as it's included (e.g. */etc/yum.conf* or */etc/yum.repos.d*).

Your first repository seems to be missing a 'name' (such as your second one has been called updates). Other than that, there's nothing technical preventing you from doing what you want. It will basically concatenate the files in */etc/yum.repos.d* together and be interpretted with the contents of */etc/yum.conf*.

Comment: You say "Technically..." - does this mean that it works, but shouldn't be done this way? Because I consider it bad style to have more than one repo configuration per `/etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo` file, but cannot find a proof for that.